# hash password different between query text and query parameter

Tags: sql, vb.net

i want to ask is it different to hashbytes by query and parameter ?
my code is

```
.CommandText = "update table.pass " _
& "set password = convert(varchar(12),HASHBYTES('MD5','" & TextEdit3.Text.ToUpper.ToString & "'),2) where userid='" + USER_ID + "'"
```

my second code is

```
.CommandText = "update table.pass " _
& " set password = convert(varchar(12),HASHBYTES('MD5',@pass),2) where userid=@userid"
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextEdit3.Text.ToUpper.ToString)
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", USER_ID)
```

[image]

for now iam using the first code, and i know it's wrong due to sql injection. so i want to use the second code. but the result was different from the first code.

what i want is, how do i use parameter but the result is same with the first code, because my predecessor use the first one

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString` on a `String`? More importantly, why are you calling `ToUpper` at all? By doing so, you are causing multiple distinct passwords to hash to the same value.

Comment: @jmcilhinney well iam using `ToUpper` because on the other application project was using it to login. if not i can't even login in this app. for `tostring` i think it's not causing any problem right .

Comment: With regards to `ToUpper`, if it's beyond your control then your hands are tied but that is a very bad implementation so don't ever do that if you have the option. If you do then passwords "password", "PASSWORD" and "PassWord" would all be considered the same, which they obviously are not. With regards to `ToString`, it's not hurting specifically but there's no good reason to use it so you shouldn't. I can think of lots of things that won't break your code but I don't see you doing any of them because they are pointless, as is `ToString` on a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `AddWithValue` assumes `nvarchar` for `String` data. It is generally recommended to use `Add` and specify the data type yourself when there is any doubt about which data type will be used.  If you do that and specify `VarChar` then you should get the same result.

EDIT: Either that or put an 'N' prefix in the first code, i.e.

```
"set password = convert(varchar(12),HASHBYTES('MD5',N'"
```

Comment: it works, i don't know that `sqldbtype` is effecting. therefore iam using `Add` and specify as `varchar`. thanks